How to display only desired countries in syncfusion_flutter_maps library
I used syncfusion_flutter_maps in flutter to load the map and use geojson data to display markers on the map.
However, I only want to show South Korea on the map. That is, I don't want to set boundaries on the map so that you can't go anywhere other than South Korea, and then show other countries that don't have data.
Here is my code...
SfMaps(
                layers: [
                  MapTileLayer(
                    initialFocalLatLng: _currentLocation ??
                        const MapLatLng(36.5, 127.5), // 초기 포컬 위치 설정
                    initialZoomLevel: 10, // 초기 줌 레벨 설정
                    urlTemplate:
                        'https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                    zoomPanBehavior: _zoomPanBehavior,
                    initialMarkersCount: (_currentLocation != null
                        ? _getTotalDataPointCount() + 1
                        : _getTotalDataPointCount()),
                    markerBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      int seaPoliceCount =
                          _showSeaPolice ? _dataPoints1.length : 0;
                      int shipDataCount =
                          _showShipData ? _dataPoints2.length : 0;
                      int hospitalDataCount =
                          _showHospitalData ? _dataPoints3.length : 0;
                      int accommodationDataCount =
                          _showAccommodationData ? _dataPoints4.length : 0;

                      int totalDataPoints = seaPoliceCount +
                          shipDataCount +
                          hospitalDataCount +
                          accommodationDataCount;

                      if (_currentLocation != null &&
                          index == totalDataPoints) {
                        return MapMarker(
                          latitude: _currentLocation!.latitude,
                          longitude: _currentLocation!.longitude,
                          child: Image.asset(
                            'assets/icons/9715440.png',
                            width: 30,
                            height: 30,
                          ),
                        );
                      }

                      if (_showSeaPolice && index < _dataPoints1.length) {
                        return MapMarker(
                          latitude: _dataPoints1[index].latitude,
                          longitude: _dataPoints1[index].longitude,
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              _showMarkerInfo(context, _properties1[index],
                                  'seaPolice');
                            },
                            child: Image.asset(
                              'assets/icons/policeicon2.png',
                              width: 36,
                              height: 36,
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      }

                      if (_showShipData &&
                          index < seaPoliceCount + _dataPoints2.length) {
                        int adjustedIndex = index - seaPoliceCount;
                        return MapMarker(
                          latitude: _dataPoints2[adjustedIndex].latitude,
                          longitude: _dataPoints2[adjustedIndex].longitude,
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              _showMarkerInfo(context,
                                  _properties2[adjustedIndex], 'ship');
                            },
                            child: Image.asset(
                              'assets/icons/shipicon2.png',
                              width: 36,
                              height: 36,
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      }

                      if (_showHospitalData &&
                          index <
                              seaPoliceCount +
                                  shipDataCount +
                                  _dataPoints3.length) {
                        int adjustedIndex =
                            index - seaPoliceCount - shipDataCount;
                        return MapMarker(
                          latitude: _dataPoints3[adjustedIndex].latitude,
                          longitude: _dataPoints3[adjustedIndex].longitude,
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              _showMarkerInfo(context,
                                  _properties3[adjustedIndex], 'hospital');
                            },
                            child: Image.asset(
                              'assets/icons/namhaHicon.png',
                              width: 36,
                              height: 36,
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      }

                      if (_showAccommodationData &&
                          index <
                              seaPoliceCount +
                                  shipDataCount +
                                  hospitalDataCount +
                                  _dataPoints4.length) {
                        int adjustedIndex = index -
                            seaPoliceCount -
                            shipDataCount -
                            hospitalDataCount;
                        return MapMarker(
                          latitude: _dataPoints4[adjustedIndex].latitude,
                          longitude: _dataPoints4[adjustedIndex].longitude,
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              _showMarkerInfo(
                                  context,
                                  _properties4[adjustedIndex],
                                  'accommodation');
                            },
                            child: Image.asset(
                              'assets/icons/namhaSicon.png',
                              width: 36,
                              height: 36,
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      }

                      return MapMarker(
                        latitude: 0,
                        longitude: 0,
                        child: Container(),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),


Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are not open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.
